# XORing two char arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I have two char arrays:

```
unsigned char a[8];
```

and

```
unsigned char b[8];
```

How can I do the XOR-operation:

```
p[i]=a[i]^b[i]
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Use `for()` loop and do it element by element

Answer (score 8):

```
std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
    std::begin(b),
    std::begin(p),
    std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());
```

Comment: +1, the solution I would have done but I'd have written a lambda as I didn't know about std::bit_xor

Comment: Btw, are you sure there exists std::bit_xor? It seems not to in C++03. Does it in C++11?

Comment: @CashCow - I'm a library guy. I don't do lambdas. <g>

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan:  It was introduced in C++11.

Comment: Use `std::bit_xor< std::remove_reference<decltype(a[0])>::type >()` to make more confusion on OP :-P

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    p[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

Provided that p is also an array of `unsigned char` with large enough size (`>=8`)

Here's another solution, but it's really bad. Just for fun's sake. Imagine there is a type that is 8 bytes long. Let the type's name be long long. You could do this (but don't :))

```
unsigned long long aa;
unsigned long long bb;

memcpy(&aa, a, 8);
memcpy(&bb, b, 8);
unsigned long long pp = a^b;
memcpy(p, &pp, 8);
```

Comment: Or you could use uint64_t, which is guaranteed to be 8 bytes long.

Comment: @nightcracker: Actually my answer is about C++03. C++11 support isn't that widespread yet.

Answer (score 0):

XOR each element individually:

```
p[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
p[1] = a[1] ^ b[1];
p[2] = a[2] ^ b[2];
p[3] = a[3] ^ b[3];
p[4] = a[4] ^ b[4];
p[5] = a[5] ^ b[5];
p[6] = a[6] ^ b[6];
p[7] = a[7] ^ b[7];
```

You could do this with a for-loop, but I did it manually here for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote there does the bitwise XOR just fine. Just put it inside a `for(int i(0); i < 8; ++i){ ... }`

Alternatively, if you want a more complicated comparison then theres this method:

In this example the char 'y' is 1 and anything else is 0. So XOR should give us true for y# and #y, but not yy or ##.

```
bool p[8];
for (int i(0); i<8; ++i)
{
  if ( a[i] == 'y')
  {
     if (b[i] == 'y')
     {
       p[i] = false;
     }
     else
     {
       p[i] = true;
     }
   }
   else
   {
     if (b[i] == 'y')
     {
       p[i] = true;
     }
     else
     {
       p[i] = false;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Armen well he's already got the ^ operator, so I was struggling to understand what he didn't know. This is a little bit of a stretch I'll admit but if he wants to XOR the chars based on a specified value rather than bitwise then this is the logic of it. i.e. I want to treat all the chars that are a specified value as true, and all those that are not as false and then XOR it... *shrug* it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  template <size_t SIZE>
  struct xor_word
  {
    template <typename T>
    static inline void crypt(T* pData, const T *key)
    {
        *pData ^= *key;

        xor_word<SIZE - 1>::crypt<T>(pData + 1, key + 1);
    }
  };

  template <>
  struct xor_word<0>
  {
    template <typename T>
    static inline void crypt(T *pData, const T *key)
    { /* nothing */ }
  };
```

and some using

```
unsigned char a[8] = ...;
unsigned char b[8] = ...;

static_assert( (sizeof(a) % sizeof(size_t)) == 0);
static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));

xor_word< sizeof(a) / sizeof(size_t) >::crypt<size_t>(
                                      reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(a),
                                      reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(b)
                                     );
```