# array...for loop

Tags: c++

I have two integer a, b and a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0 ;i<8 ;++i)
{
    if((b & (0x01 << i)) != 0x00)  
    {
        // 
        c ^= (a << i);
    }
}
```

how can i do this when a and b are stored in char arrays?

```
unsigned char test (unsigned char* a[], unsigned char* b[])
{

    for(int i=0 ;i<8 ;++i)
    {
        if((b[i] & (0x01 << i)) != 0x00)  
        {
            shiftleft(a);
            c[i] ^= a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work in just the same way with the same operators.
It depends what shiftleft is doing, and you probably want c[i] ^= *a;

Comment: You should totally use better formatting.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question: [XORing of two char arrays c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122988/xoring-of-two-char-arrays-c)?!?

Answer (score 0):

I think - guessing what you want to do it should be.

```
unsigned char test (unsigned char* a[], unsigned char* b[])
{
    for(int i=0 ;i<8 ;++i)
    {
        if((b[i] & (0x01 << i)) != 0x00)  
        {
            c[i] ^= (*a)<<i;
        }
    }
}
```

It depends what you want to do with the rest of the 'a' array though

Answer (score 0):

Since a and b are now arrays, you have to first index and dereference the element you want to work with.  So, for example, instead of

```
c ^= (a << i);
```

You could do:

```
c[i] ^= (a[i] << i);
```

Please note that since ^= depends on the previous value, c[i] should be initialized to something meaningful before you begin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to iterate over your arrays, applying the bit shifts on each item.  You will need to provide a count for the size of your arrays.

```
unsigned char test (int count, unsigned char* a[], unsigned char* b[])
{
    char c = 0;

    for( int iarray = 0; iarray < count; ++iarray )
    {
        for(int i=0 ;i<8 ;++i)
        {
            if((b[iarray] & (0x01 << i)) != 0x00)  
            {
                c ^= (a[iarray] << i)
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

If you want 'c' to also be an array, that is easy enough to do, but you will probably have to allocate it in memory and return a pointer to the memory.